# Can you use global variable from config file in index.php - Fat Free Framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I would like to set a global variable called CONTROLLERPATH in my config.ini file and then use that variable in my index.php file to route the GET requests to the correct controller in my directory structure.   I am doing the following and F3 cannot make out the value of CONTROLLERPATH.

My `config.ini` file:

```
[global]

DEBUG=3
UI=ui/
CONTROLLERPATH='app/controllers/'
```

Within my `index.php` file:

```
$f3->config('config.ini');
$f3->route('GET /', CONTROLLERPATH . 'indexController->index');
```

I have also tried to ditch the config.ini way and setting the value of controllerPath as follows in my index.php file, and it still does not work:

```
$f3->set('controllerPath', 'app/controllers/');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables defined in ini files are [framework variables](http://fatfreeframework.com/framework-variables), not PHP constants.

It means that they are accessible via the framework, using one of the following syntaxes:

- `$f3->get('CONTROLLERPATH')`
- `$f3['CONTROLLERPATH']`
- `$f3->CONTROLLERPATH`

Comment: Very helpful! When I use the CONTROLLERPATH as a framework variable, it is still not working if I try to concatenate within the routing as follows: $f3->route('GET /', $f3->CONTROLLERPATH . 'indexController->index');  I just need a way to tell F3 that all of my controllers are in the app/controllers folder

Comment: PHP namespaces are identified by *backslashes* not forward slashes. So your ini entry should rather look like `CONTROLLERPATH = app\controllers\ ` (notice also how single quotes are not required). Also your file structure should follow the [autoloader](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#the-f3-autoloader) requirements (see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262719/implementing-namespaces-in-fatfree-framework/27312633#27312633) for more details).