# How to load or include/require 3rd party library php files in a controller only when needed in Fat Free Framework (f3)

Tags: php, ajax, fat-free-framework

I am trying to include a file for the ExactTarget api inside a controller. Basically, an ajax request submits a form to a route /send. In the controller for that route I have a class, but it fails when it makes a call to the ExactTarget library.

```
class sendexacttarget{
  public function send($f3)
  {
    $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
  }
}
```

I don't want to load the ExactTarget file in the index.php, because then it will load on every request. Ideally, I'd like to just load it here, in the send function. I've tried require() and include() but neither work.

I'm trying to include one file exacttarget.php and that file has a require statement calling soap-wsse.php which has another require statement calling xmlseclibs.php.

So first question: Is it possible to load these files from the controller and if so how?

The second part of the question is this. I am able to combine all of the PHP from those three files into one file and include from the index.php, but I have not been successful calling them as separate files. I have tried this:

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','App/Controllers/;vendor/exacttarget/xmlseclibs.php;vendor/exacttarget/soap-wsse.php;vendor/exacttarget/exacttarget.php');
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried this from another SO thread:

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','App/Controllers/;vendor/exacttarget/');
$params = require 'vendor/exacttarget/exacttarget.php';
```

Doesn't work. This last bit of code I thought worked for a bit, but then it stopped working. I'm wondering if there is some caching going on?

In any case, if anyone can please help me include this library, even if on all pages I'd be very grateful. Also, this library I'm using is not available via composer so I don't think using composers autoload is an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the semi-colon in `App/Controllers/;vendor/exacttarget/` a typo? Very new to PHP here...

Comment: I don't think so, looks like it's a list of directories separated by semi-colon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework autoloader expects the following conditions in order to be working:

- one class per file
- each file named like the class it contains and located in a directory structure representating its namespace

See the [documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/routing-engine#TheF3Autoloader) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262719/implementing-namespaces-in-fatfree-framework/2731263) for more details.

Since the external library you're trying to load doesn't meet those requirements, I suggest you three solutions:

1) require all the dependencies inside your controller:

```
  public function send($f3) {
    require('vendor/exacttarget/xmlseclibs.php');
    require('vendor/exacttarget/soap-wsse.php.php');
    require('vendor/exacttarget/exacttarget.php');
    $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
  }
```

2) create a service that will require all the dependencies and return an ExactTargetSoapClient instance:

```
// index.php
f3->SOAP = function($wsdl,array $options=[]) {
    require_once('vendor/exacttarget/xmlseclibs.php');
    require_once('vendor/exacttarget/soap-wsse.php.php');
    require_once('vendor/exacttarget/exacttarget.php');
    return new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl,$options+['trace'=>1]);
}

// controller
public function send($f3) {
  $client = $f3->SOAP($wsdl);
}
```

NB: if the $wsdl and $options arguments are the same all other your app, you can even remove the function arguments and have a simple `$f3->SOAP()`.

3) concatenate the three files into one single file properly named and have it autoloaded:

```
// vendor/exacttargetsoapclient.php
<?php
class ExactTargetSoapClient extends SoapClient {

// etc.

class WSSESoap {

// etc.

/**
* xmlseclibs.php
* etc.
```

Now set up the autoloader:

```
// index.php
$f3->AUTOLOAD = 'App/Controllers/;vendor/';
```

And you're done:

```
// controller
  public function send($f3) {
  $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));
}
```

Comment: I think part of the problem I was having was that I was working locally and the api doesn't work locally for some reason. Once I uploaded things to the server it worked. So it may not have been my includes, but I still wanted to know the "proper" way to do this and your answer is great. I'm going to see if I can reconfigure everything.

Comment: One other thing if you would indulge me. I stored the passwords for my ExactTarget connection in the config.ini, but it seems like if this is a plugin, then that is not very portable. Is there another place to store them outside of the controller, but with or near the controller?

Comment: What do you mean by "not very portable"? I think that config.ini is a great place to store that kind of information. But maybe you're talking about a way to differentiate server-specific settings (.ini file) from app-specific settings? I usually store the server-specific settings in an `etc/` folder (which is not version controlled) while I store app-specific settings in the application `src/` folder (which is version controlled). Another solution could be, if you choose solution #2, to hard-code the credentials in the service definition (inside `index.php`).

Comment: I guess config.ini is a good place, I just meant that if someone wanted to reuse my ExactTarget Controller they would have to also update config.ini, but that's probably to be expected

Comment: By the way I finally moved the require statement to the controller, but I could not get three separate require statements to work. The only way I could get it to work was to concatenate all files into one file and require that.

Answer (score 0):

The `AUTOLOAD` autoloader doesn't support file names. It looks like you are using `Composer` so please use its autoloader:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

Please adjust the `vendor` path relative (or use an absolute path) to the file which is requiring the `autoload.php` file.